# fill autocomplete box on selecting data in other autocomplete box in Light Switch 2011

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

i have a table x having two relationship from two tables.
One is company having column id and Company.
Other is Department having column id company and Department.
Again Company is Foreign key in Department.

In light-switch, i have add data screen for   table x.
It is showing Company and Department as auto-complete box.

Now i want to filter Department as per selected value in Company Auto-complete Box.
I don't want to use custom control. Is it possible directly in LightSwitch

I have tried to apply filter, but i don't get how i pass current selected Company name.

Can any one have a link for any blog or post from which i can get how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called nested, or cascading combo boxes. These two blog posts should give you what you need:

[LightSwitch – Nested AutoCompleteBox for data entry](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry/)

[LightSwitch – Nested AutoCompleteBox for data entry Part 2](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry-part-2/)